#  Microsoft.Web.Administration - NullReferenceException with httpErrors in ApplicationHost.Config

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to figure out why I am getting a `NullReferenceException` with the following code. Everything seems to look like it is nested properly.  I am using `Microsoft.Web.Administration` and I am attempting to modify the prefixLanguageFilePath for all the errors.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
    public static void ModifyCustomErrDir(string dir)
    {
        try
        {
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

            config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpErrors").ChildElements["error"].Attributes["prefixLanguageFilePath"].Value = dir;
        }
        catch (ServerManagerException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    <httpErrors lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath">
        <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="401.htm" />
        <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="403.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="404.htm" />
        <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="405.htm" />
        <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="406.htm" />
        <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="412.htm" />
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="500.htm" />
        <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="501.htm" />
        <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="502.htm" />
    </httpErrors>
```

---

Edit:

I got it working by looping through the collection without denoting the error tag and just looking for the attribute. I will have to come back to it to see if there would be any unintended adverse "features" by doing it this way.

```
var httpErrorsCollection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpErrors")
       .GetCollection(); 

foreach (var error in httpErrorsCollection) 
    error.Attributes["prefixLanguageFilePath"].Value = dir;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints. In particular, break that long expression apart and see which part is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpErrors").ChildElements["error"].
//        Attributes["prefixLanguageFilePath"].Value = dir;

var errorSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpErrors");
// check errorSection    
var errors = errorSection.ChildElements["error"];
// check errors
errors.Attributes["prefixLanguageFilePath"].Value = dir;
```

etc

Comment: Henk, thanks but I cannot debug this as I do not have IIS installed locally and I do not have admin rights to install debugging remotely on the IIS server.  The only feedback I am getting is the catch exception.

Comment: Ok, so I validated "errorSection" however "errors" is uninitialized.  So now based on looking at the XML, how is that possible?

Comment: Not sure - there are multiple candidates, the return can only be 1. Or `null`.

Comment: I got it working by looping through the collection without denoting the error tag and just looking for the attribute.  I will have to come back to it to see if there would be any unintended adverse "features" by doing it this way.

Comment: `                var httpErrorsCollection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpErrors").GetCollection();

                foreach (var error in httpErrorsCollection)
                    error.Attributes["prefixLanguageFilePath"].Value = dir;`

Comment: OK, Note that you can _edit_ your question. Relevant info should not be in comments.